# desktop shortcut does not work

Tags: php, batch

I have created **batch file that start apache and mysql server,copy try.exe on desktop and run project in browser**.that works fine.**but onclick desktop shorcut error occured.error is windows can not find mysql_start.exe**. actully i **convert try.bat into try.exe**. IN installation folder it work fine,but on shortcut error occured.                                  the code is:

```
@echo off
echo Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
echo Bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
echo Please close this command only for Shutdown
echo Apache 2 is starting ...

start  xampp_start.exe /h
start   firefox.exe http://localhost/xampp/newamcs12/index.php
copy "try.exe" %userprofile%\desktop
if errorlevel 255 goto finish
if errorlevel 1 goto error
goto finish

:error
echo.
echo Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
echo Apache could not be started

pause

:finish
CLS
EXIT
```

Comment: The only thing I could think of is either the filepath is incorrect for one of them, or the path to your userprofile has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

It all looks right to me.  Try double-checking your file name and user name, as @:Prof Pickle said.